# Apply ColorFilter / ColorMatrix to turn image completely white

Tags: android, android-progressbar, colormatrix, colormatrixfilter

I have a circular ProgressBar on my Toolbar to show some indeterminate progress happening, however the default style of the ProgressBar (the only one I know that makes it into a circular ring) is the same color as the toolbar (the 'colorPrimary' color).

The styles I tried are `?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge` and `?android:attr/progressBarStyleLargeInverse`, both get the same color as the toolbar, hence they are not visible.

I read that I can change the color by applying a color filter as such:

```
toolbarProgress.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(Color.WHITE, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

However, I cannot find a single 'PorferDuff.Mode' that turns a colored image into a completely white image (while keeping the alpha transparency intact).

Instead of using the PorterDuff modes I can also apply a ColorMatrix. For example to turn it into grayscale I can use this:

```
        ColorMatrixColorFilter filter = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(new float[] {
            0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0, 0,
            0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0, 0,
            0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0, 0,
            0, 0, 0, 1, 0
    });
    toolbarProgress.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(filter);
```

Same problem here: I can't find the correct matrix that turns the image completely white. Grayscale comes close but it turns into a grayish color and not pure white.

What I want is to turn all colored pixels into pure white, and leave all alpha pixels transparent.

Unless there is an easier way to change the color of the native ProgressBar..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it have to be `ColorMatrixColorFilter`? You can use `DrawableCompat` to tint `Drawables`.

```
Drawable drawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(progressBar.getIndeterminateDrawable());
DrawableCompat.setTint(drawable, Color.WHITE);
toolbarProgress.setIndeterminateDrawable(drawable);
```

Comment: Thanks! I was not aware of the existence of DrawableCompat (I suppose this is in the support library?). I should have mentioned I need to be backward compatible to sdk 11 (so cannot use the tint) but this should work fine then hopefully. I will try it later, thanks.

Comment: Correct. It's part of android.support.v4.

Comment: Thanks, it works with some minor modifications. Instead of setting back the 'drawable' object as the indeterminateDrawable, I had to use the result of the DrawableCompat.wrap function, eg:

Drawable wrapped = DrawableCompat.wrap(drawable);
...
toolbarProgress.setIndeterminateDrawable(wrapped);

Additionally, support library 22.1.0 or higher is required. Anything lower does nothing except ensure there is no crash on Android < 5.0, but it does not apply the tint.